# SQL Server: Get Latest Auto-Increment Value

Tags: sql-server

How do I get the next auto-increment value of some column in *Microsoft SQL Server*?

Example: Given we have an auto-incrementing column **X** in table **Y**:

```
    +-----+
T   |  X  |--- AUTO INCREMENTING INTEGER COLUMN (X)
A   +=====+
B   |  0  |
L   +-----+
E   |  1  |
    +-----+
Y   |  3  |--- NOTICE HOW 2 IS SKIPPED, THIS IS BECAUSE IT WAS DELETED, YET
    +-----+        THE AUTO INCREMENT REMEMBERS THIS AND WILL NEVER USE 2 AGAIN
```

In the above example, the next auto increment value will be **4**. However, if we delete **3**, then our next auto increment value will *still be **4***. How can we attain this value in a SQL statement?

**EDIT 1:** This question is specific to SQL Server. Please post answers that pertain to SQL Server.

**EDIT 2:** If you are going to downvote this post then please provide the courtesy of explaining why. In particular, please indicate how this is " an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: why did you tag mysql if it's specific to sql-server :/

Comment: Apologies, I meant to correct that in Edit 1

Comment: imagine numbers are inserted in order like 1,2,3,4 .now 2,3 are deleted.so you want the next increment to start at 2,3 and continue with 5

Comment: @Kritner Thank you for that duplicate link. I searched for 1/2 hour and couldn't find any answers relating to SQL Server.

Comment: If you are going to downvote this post then please provide the courtesy of explaining why. In particular, please indicate how this is " an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).